# Having problem reaching client which don't have static ip address

Tags: c#, .net, .net-remoting

**i am making a messenger over internet.**

it has a server which listens to clients but when it try to send the reply to any request to client it shows the error of client not found. 
however my clients are connecting to that server because it has a static ip address and live server.

having problem reaching client because they can be behind any firewall or network and dont have static ip addresses. so how can i reach to my client??
any Suggestions..

Comment: Static IP is the least of your concerns: ICQ did it with dynamic IPs, back in 1996, before UPnP was a common subsystem in routers, and DDNS (like no-ip) was just a baby.

Probably, what you need is to understand how TCP sessions work, or whatever binding protocol you use. Google it, and you'll find quite a few SO questions about WCF and .NET Remoting involving routers and firewalls. Show us some code, or at least provide more info on your implementation.

Comment: Some code will definitely help. =)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the firewall isn't causing any problems and also checkout NoIp(http://www.no-ip.com/), it allows any computer to effectively have a static ip. Just sign up then click on "Add Host". Call the host whatever you want then, on your client program set the ip as the name of the host. As long as the no-ip duc program (a very small, portable program you need to download) is running, it should work fine :) Hope it works, ell.